# Magento - Move Customer Edit Form into Account Dashboard

Tags: magento, dashboard

My magento store currently has the default layout for my customer account dashboard. 
One of the sections in the dashboard is the contact information which uses the template

```
customer/account/info.phtml
```

If a customer wants to edit their contact information they go from:

```
www.site.com/customer/account/
(calls template customer/account/dashboard.phtml and customer/account/info.phtml)
```

to

```
www.site.com/customer/account/edit/
(calls template customer/form/edit.phtml)
```

Is there a way i can move the actual edit form into the dashboard itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want add below code in customer.xml and

add

```
      <customer_account translate="label">
........
        <reference name="content">

  <!-- add below .... -->
          <block type="customer/form_edit" name="you_customer_edit" 
    template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
<!--- end of -->
        </reference>
```

Comment: solved with very similar http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32978/move-customer-edit-form-into-account-dashboard#32986

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below snippet

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <update handle="customer_account_edit" />

</customer_account_index>
```

`<update handle="customer_account_edit" />` it will take the layout of customer/account/edit